# Way to make this homogoneous ODE seperable?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

## Is my algebra correct, turning this:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{4y-3x}{2x-y}$$

## Into this:

```
I split into the difference of the two fractions,
then factored x out of the left fraction, and factored y
out of the right fraction, getting:
```

$$\frac{4\frac{y}{x}}{x(1-\frac{y}{x})} - \frac{3\frac{x}{y}}{2\frac{x}{y}-1}$$

Now I can substitute $v = \frac{y}{x}, v^{-1}= \frac{x}{y}$, right?

Then separate? Then integrate?

Comment: You lost a $2$ in the first denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of doing such a question is to divide the top and bottom of the fraction by $x$ yielding $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{4\frac{y}{x} - 3}{2 - \frac{y}{x}}$$ and then use the substitition $v = \frac{y}{x} \implies y = vx$ so that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = v + x\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}$ to get $$v + x\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{4v}{2-v} - \frac{3}{2-v}$$ can you take it from there? If not, you can continue by subtracting $v$ from both sides, giving you $$x \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x} = - \frac{(v+3)(v-1)}{v-2} \implies \int \frac{2-v}{(v-1)(v+3)} \, \mathrm{d}v = \ln |x| + c$$ where partial fraction decomposition on the rational function of $v$ yields $$\frac{2-v}{(v-1)(v+3)} = \frac{1}{4(v-1)} - \frac{5}{4(v+3)}$$ Hence we get $$\frac{1}{4} \ln |v-1| - \frac{5}{4}\ln |v+3| = \ln |x| + c$$

Comment: Thank you.  I factored the x out of the both the left and right fractions and got $\frac{4v}{2-v}-\frac{3}{2-v}$ on the RHS and $v + x\frac{dv}{dx}$ on the LHS, as you wrote.  Now I am trying to simplify it and get all the V terms on the left and x on the RHS, so I can integrate.  I'm struggling to get the LHS into a form that is easily integrable.  So far I've gotten to $\frac{2-v}{(v-1)(v+3}dv = \frac{1}{x}dx$.  The RHS is obv. $ln|x|$.  The LHS I will have to do partial fraction decomposition??

Comment: PFD: A = 1/4, B = -5/4, $\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{v-1} - \frac{\frac{5}{4}}{v+3}$, is this right?

Comment: @eestack, very much correct, yes! Good job.

Comment: Now I got: $\frac{1}{4}ln(v-4) - \frac{5}{4}ln(v+12) = ln(x)+c$

Comment: Thanks!  Now I should substitute v = y/x into this, correct?  And I'm done?

Comment: @eestack, that's not particularly right! You should get $\frac{1}{4} \ln (v-1) - \frac{5}{4}\ln (v+3) = \ln x + c$.

Comment: You could simplify it a bit, collect all the $\ln$ terms together first and then substitute $v = \frac{y}{x}$ to get the solution and then, yes, you are done.

Comment: Okay great!  Thank you again. :)  One last question for this problem: what is the point of this?  If I have some initial condition, now I can solve for C, and find out the value of Y at any time (value of x) (this is a question)??

Comment: If you have initial conditions, that is you need to know what $x$ and $y$ are equal to intially, then you can solve for $c$ to get the solution as being a specific solution. Otherwise, if you just leave $c$ you get a family of solutions. So the function + 1, function + 2, function - 100, function + any number all count as solutions if you don't have the initial conditions. Think of them as shifting curves up or down. Solving for $c$ gives you only one curve.

Comment: Oh yes I distributed the 4 into the denominator before integrating, but also left the fraction outside as a constant coefficient when integrating.  Thanks for catching this.

Comment: If you have the time will you look @ my comment on @Nemo s answer?  I don't understand his method.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation belongs to a class of homogeneous ODE
$$f(x,y)dx+ g(x,y)dy=0 $$

where $f(x,y)=x(-3+\frac{y}{x})$ and $g(x,y)=x(-2+\frac{y}{x})$

The typical way to solve this is : let $u=\frac{y}{x}$ hence $y=ux$

therefore $dy=udx +xdu$

plug these into your ODE, simplify, you will get a first order ODE in term of $u$
and you can solve it using the method of separation.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it maybe it will help you:$$\frac { dy }{ dx } =\frac { 4y-3x }{ 2x-y } =\frac { 4\frac { y }{ x } -3 }{ 2-\frac { y }{ x }  } \\ \frac { y }{ x } =t$$
$$ y=xt\\ y^{ \prime  }=t+x{ t }^{ \prime  }\\ t+x{ t }^{ \prime  }=\frac { 4t-3 }{ 2-t } $$ $$ x{ t }^{ \prime  }=\frac { { t }^{ 2 }+2t-3 }{ 2-t } =\frac { \left( t+3 \right) \left( t-1 \right)  }{ 2-t } \\ \int { \frac { 2-t }{ \left( t+3 \right) \left( t-1 \right)  } dt } =\int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } \\ \frac { 2-t }{ \left( t+3 \right) \left( t-1 \right)  } =\frac { A }{ t+3 } +\frac { B }{ t-1 } $$ $$2-t=A\left( t-1 \right) +B\left( t+3 \right) =\left( A+B \right) t+3B-A$$
$A=-\frac { 5 }{ 4 } $,$B=\frac { 1 }{ 4 } $
$$ -\frac { 5 }{ 4 } \int { \frac { dt }{ t+3 }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \int { \frac { dt }{ t-1 } = } \int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } $$
$$-\frac { 5 }{ 4 } \ln { \left| t+3 \right|  } +\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \ln { \left| t-1 \right| =\ln { Cx }  } $$ $$\ln { \sqrt [ 4 ]{ \left| \frac { t-1 }{ \left( t+3 \right) ^{ 5 } }  \right|  }  } =\ln { Cx } $$ $$ \frac { t-1 }{ \left( t+3 \right) ^{ 5 } } =Cx^{ 4 }$$ $$ \frac { \frac { y }{ x } -1 }{ { \left( \frac { y }{ x } +3 \right)  }^{ 5 } } =Cx^{ 4 }$$

Comment: $\int\frac{1}{x}dx = ln|x| + C$ whic does not equal $lnCx$, right? Or is this the same thing?  And how did you go from the answer w/ the natural logs to the 4th root?

Comment: @eestack $ln x + c = \ln x + \ln e^c = \ln xe^c$. Now just define a new constant C = e^c to get $ln Cx$.

Comment: C is the constant,you can write C as lnC what ever you want,beacause C is the constant so you can do it as i did it.

Comment: @eestack $\frac{1}{4} ln x = \ln x^{1/4}$.

Comment: sorry for my english my friend,i try use few words,more math,hence i can't explain more detail

Comment: @ZainPatel great I understand thank you :)

Comment: @Nemo great I understand thank you :)